# How to freeze the screen using windows APIs?

Tags: .net, winapi

Is there an API on windows that freezes everything for a number seconds then resume it normally again?

Comment: Are you looking for ways to get users to hate your application? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/02/10084449.aspx

Comment: I am curious if there is one that do that!

Comment: No, it's a project for fun actually.

Comment: I can think of a *lot* of code that will freeze a computer. Probably less that will "resume it normally again."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seriously doubt there is. What you could do, however, is to take a snapshot of whatever is currently displayed and then create a window filling the entire screen (or screens) and fill that window with the snapshot you've just taken. That would give the appearance of freezing everything.

Of course, it only gives the appearance of freezing everything; all processes and windows would update as normal behind your "snapshot window".

Comment: This sounds like an alternate idea, I might consider it if I couldn't find another way. Thanks :)

Comment: Windows operating normally is probably a good thing. Really freezing windows has bad side-effects. Like network connections die,...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it recently, but I got burned by that once a few years ago:

Set the priority of a process to Real-Time and enter a loop. On multi-core systems you probably need one thread per logical core.

Side effects include overheating the computer.